# How to place Clojurescript npm-deps in production setup?

Tags: npm, clojurescript, figwheel, cljsbuild, clojurescript-javascript-interop

this is a simple question, but I have been puzzling over it for a while now and it doesn't have much documentation to look at:

I've got a development setup with ClojureScript, figwheel, npm deps working just fine for me. But when I produce a production, compiled JS file, it does not find the npm dependency files. So where and how do I place which of these packages in the production web server, so that they will be found and loaded?

Regards,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All files required to run your JS will be included in the compilation output after `:advanced` optimizations. No `node_modules` files will be required at all so there should not be any need to place them anywhere. Only the files produced by the build directly should be loaded.

`:npm-deps` however is an alpha feature with many known issues. You can use alternate solutions like [webpack](https://clojurescript.org/guides/webpack) or [shadow-cljs](https://github.com/thheller/shadow-cljs) which work much more reliable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried just using `:advanced` but that didn't work. I guess I'll look at the tools you recommended.

Comment: So do these two tools you mention work with any npm module? It doesn't seem clear to me from reading the pages...

Comment: I'm the author of `shadow-cljs` and yes it works with nearly all `npm` modules. Just `npm install the-thing` and `(:require ["the-thing" :as x])`, no additional steps needed. `webpack` is a bit more involved and you should follow the guide I linked. Maybe your `:npm-deps` setup can be fixed but you did not provide enough information to help. Maybe post your build config and the errors you get.

Comment: Well, if `shadow-cljs` is more mature, I'll just use that. Thanks.

Comment: As you are the author of `shadow-cljs`, could I ask one more thing? what is the appropriate target for using the compiled file with a web worker (using servant)?

Comment: `:browser` has built-in support for workers. See https://shadow-cljs.github.io/docs/UsersGuide.html#_web_workers